# How to use CompletableFuture and functional interfaces of java8?

Tags: java, asynchronous, interface, functional-programming, completable-future

I would like to replace the class `CompteBancaire` to a functional interfaces, can anyone show me how to do that?

Below is the code snippet, I want to use `CompletableFuture` in `verserArgent` and `retirerArgent` methods for async task.

```
package myclasses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CompteBancaire {

    private int numC;
    private int nbTraces;
    public static int nbComptes;
    public double solde;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;

    private List<Double> tracesComptes = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @Constructeur non pramÃ©trÃ©
     */
    public CompteBancaire() {
        this.tracesComptes = new ArrayList<>();
        nbComptes++;

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param numC
     * @param solde
     * @param nom
     * @param prenom
     *
     * @Constructeur pramÃ©trÃ©
     */
    public CompteBancaire(int numC, double solde, String nom, String prenom) {
        this.numC = numC;
        this.solde = solde;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.tracesComptes = new ArrayList<>();
        nbComptes++;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return @getters && setters
     *
     *
     */
    public int getNumC() {
        return numC;
    }

    public void setNumC(int numC) {
        this.numC = numC;
    }

    public int getNbTraces() {
        return nbTraces;
    }

    public void setNbTraces(int nbTraces) {
        this.nbTraces = nbTraces;
    }

    public double getSolde() {
        return solde;
    }

    public void setSolde(double solde) {
        this.solde = solde;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param tracesCompte
     */
    public void setTracesCompte(List<Double> tracesCompte) {
        this.tracesComptes = tracesCompte;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param montant
     * @return
     * @throws tp3.ErreurNegatif
     * @Methode qui depose de l'argent au compte (versement)
     *
     */

    public void verserArgent(double montant) throws ErreurNegatif, Throwable {
        if (montant > 0) {
            solde += montant;
            tracesComptes.add(nbTraces, solde);
            nbTraces++;
        } else {
            throw new ErreurNegatif();
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @Methode qui retire de l'argent du compte
     *
     */
    void retirerArgent(double montant) throws ErreurNegatif {
        if (solde - montant > 0) {
            solde -= montant;
            tracesComptes.add(nbTraces, solde);
            nbTraces++;
        } else {
            throw new ErreurNegatif();
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return @Methode qui affiche les informations relatives au compte
     *
     *
     */
    public String description() {

        return "Titulaire du compte:" + nom + " " + prenom + ", NumÃ©ro compte:" + numC + ", Solde:" + solde;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional interface is an **interface which has only one method**. Your class has (1) more then one method and (2) contains methods with a body, which means that it **can't be converted to a functional interface**. You can, of course, create an interface and then implement it.

**Please rewrite you code in english and edit your answer!**

```
public void verserArgent(double montant) throws ErreurNegatif, Throwable {
   if (montant > 0) {
       solde += montant;
       tracesComptes.add(nbTraces, solde);
       nbTraces++;
   } else {
       throw new ErreurNegatif();
   }
}
```

this is the method you want to perform async. (I did not understand you completely, but i think that is what you want to do). Performing this method async does not make much sense because it is not expensive.

CompletableFuture can be simply instanciated and completed with its method `complete(T result)`.

For example:

```
    public CompletableFuture<Void> verserArgent(double montant) throws ErreurNegatif, Throwable {
   CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
   if (montant > 0) {
       solde += montant;
       tracesComptes.add(nbTraces, solde);
       nbTraces++;
       future.complete(null);
   } else {
       throw new ErreurNegatif();
   }
   return future;
}
```

Again, this works, but does not make sense.

Comment: i am supposed to use CompletableFuture in my methods even though they are not expensive, any help plz

Comment: I have answered your questions and written a function which uses CompletableFuture.